# Не понимаю почему код discord py не работает

Tags: python, discord, minecraft

Написал простого бота для отображения онлайна майнкрафт сервера в названии голосового канала и он какое то короткое время правильно работал но потом не понятно после чего перестал

```
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer
from discord.ext import tasks
import discord
config = {
    'token': 'мой токен',
    'name': None,
    'ID': None,
    'pref': '!'
}

bot = discord.Client()



class MyCog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.channels.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5)
    async def channels(self):
        server = MinecraftServer.lookup("ip сервера")
        status = server.status()
        for i in bot.get_all_channels():
            if 'Игроков онлайн: ' in str(i):
                await i.edit(name='Игроков онлайн: {}'.format(status.players.online))
                print('Игроков онлайн: {}'.format(status.players.online))
MyCog()

bot.run(config['token'])
```

Не знаю важно ли это но я много раз перезапускал бота в попытках заставить его работать

Comment: Ошибки какие-нибудь вылазят?

Comment: Мой гадальный шар говорит, что название канала не всегда меняется или меняется только один раз, а потом перестает. Название канала часто нельзя менять, нужно выдерживать таймаут, точно не помню сколько но минут 5 точно.

Comment: @Super3283u ошибок нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу обратить внимание, что вы лупаете на каждые 5 секунд, в то время как у ботов есть рейт лимит, по которому они работают. Проще говоря вы не можете изменять канал каждые 5 секунд. Подробнее: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits